# How to add editable JEditorPane with scroll or movable inside?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am going to make a big box and the box uses to put many words inside. Kind of like a description box and editable.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

A `JEditorPane` is for display HTML.

Typically you would use either a `JTextArea` (plain text) or a `JTextPane` (styled text) for display text.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Keep a link to the `Swing Tutorial` handy for information on all Swing basics.